# cmake cannot find the libs for opencv4

Tags: opencv, cmake, linker, shared-libraries, undefined

i am writing code in C++ and for some reason i the cmake cannot find the libs for the opencv4. i am using linux machine (Ubuntu). here is the cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(Robot-Navigation-Workshop)

# Add the cmake directory to the module path
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")


# Find playerc++ library and headers
find_package(playerc++ REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PLAYERCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})


# Find OpenCV library
# Find OpenCV library
set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/)
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(Robot-Navigation ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

# Add the executables
add_executable(Robot-Navigation main.cpp
        src/Navigation.cpp
        src/Navigation.h
        src/Room.cpp
        src/Room.h
        src/Route.cpp
        src/Route.h
        src/DataStructure.h
        src/MapGenerator.cpp
        src/MapGenerator.h)



# Link the playerc++ and OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(Robot-Navigation ${PLAYERCXX_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

the first packges playercxx is linked okay but the opencv is not linked:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "Robot-Navigation" which is not
  built by this project.
```

i have the opencv headers file in the folder: "/usr/include" inside there is folder opencv4 and inside there is opencv2.

the library file of opencv is in the path:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
```

inside there is a file name "opencv4.pc" inside:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include/opencv4

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 4.5.4
Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_barcode -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_ml -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
Libs.private: -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

i tried to change the cmake using the chatgpt, reinstall the opencv4 library, adding the the "PKG_CONFIG_PATH" the folder to opencv4.pc nothing worked.

Comment: The first time you call `target_link_libraries` (in the `if(OpenCV_FOUND)` branch), the target `Robot-Navigation` has **not created** yet. This is what the error message tells you. The problem has nothing common with "cmake cannot find the libs for opencv4".